# Cognito Forms - Dropdown Options

Tags: cognito-forms, dropbox

I'm working on a committee volunteer form in Cognito Forms and have used dropbox for a member's selection. I have an error message that will appear if their responses in subsequent boxes match a previous box. HOWEVER, it also shows the error message if they select nothing. I don't want to require them to make a selection in all fields. Any way to do this without getting the error message for empty fields?

Comment: Don't create a duplicate question.  [edit the original question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/172345/edit) and submit for reopening.  Please take the [Tour] and review [ask].